# How to create Stacked bar chart from JSON in chart.js

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js, bar-chart

I want to create stacked bar chart but I don't know how to do this and 
I don't know about put value in chart by json
I have Json data following :

```js
var setdata = [{
      "data": [{
              "month" : "January",
               "name" : "Alex",
               "count" : 10
      }]
    },
     {
      "data": [{
              "month" : "February",
               "name" : "Alex",
               "count" : 20
     },
     {  
      "data": [{
              "month" : "February",
               "name" : "John",
               "count" : 30
     },
     {  
      "data": [{
              "month" : "February",
               "name" : "Mark",
               "count" : 40
     }]
              },
    {
      "data": [{
              "month" : "March",
               "name" : "Alex",
               "count" : 10
     },
     {  
              "month" : "March",
               "name" : "John",
               "count" : 20
     }]
    }
    ]
```

I want to create stacked bar chart as :

```
|                _
|               | | Mark
|               |_|
|               | |                   _
|               | | John             | |
|               |_|                  | | John
|               | |                  |_|
|  _            | |                  | |
| | |Alex       | | Alex             | | Alex
|_|_|___________|_|__________________|_|_______
 January      February              March
                Months
```

help me, please .
thanks.
[bar chart in chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html)

Comment: Please refer this document http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/ and create your dataset as per mentioned

Comment: The link you posted describes the steps how to do it?

Comment: How to crete dataset as http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/  . I don't know to do.

Comment: remove useless code snippet

Answer (score 1):

You can try [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_campaign=stackoverflow_comments) instead to make your charting process delightful. It allows you to instantly create the chart without requiring extensive knowledge of the data structures. And did I mention that the charts look beautiful?

Using FusionCharts Stacked Charts, I have created a sample for you in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8uk5rw4/) using your data.

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {


 var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'stackedcolumn2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '550',
    height: '450',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Alex-John-Mark",
        "subCaption": "",
        "xAxisname": "Month",
        "yAxisName": "Units",

    "paletteColors": "#4A148C,#004D40, #FF6F00",
    "bgColor": "#ffffff",
    "borderAlpha": "20",
    "showCanvasBorder": "0",
    "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
    "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
    "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
    "legendShadow": "0",
    "valueFontColor": "#ffffff",
    "showXAxisLine": "1",
    "xAxisLineColor": "#999999",
    "divlineColor": "#999999",
    "divLineIsDashed": "1",
    "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
    "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
    "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
    "showHoverEffect": "1"
  },
  "categories": [{
    "category": [{
        "label": "January"
      }, {
        "label": "February"
      }, {
        "label": "March"
      }

    ]
  }],
  "dataset": [{
    "seriesname": "Alex",
    "data": [{
        "value": "10"
      }, {
        "value": "20"
      },

      {
        "value": "10"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "seriesname": "John",
    "data": [{
        "value": "0"
      }, {
        "value": "30"
      },

      {
        "value": "20"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "seriesname": "Mark",
    "data": [{
        "value": "0"
      }, {
        "value": "40"
      },

      {
        "value": "0"
      }
    ]
  }]


  }
  }).render();
});
```

Let me know if this solves your purpose.

Answer (score -1):

For This purpose, you can use chart.js
I think, this may help